# How to remove some extra tuples and lists and print some extra stuff between the strings in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, tuples

```
 bounds = reader.readtext(np.array(images[0]), min_size=0,slope_ths=0.2, ycenter_ths=0.7, height_ths=0.6,width_ths=0.8,decoder='beamsearch',beamWidth=10) 
 print(bounds)
```

The output for the above code is

I do have a string format like

```
[([[1004, 128], [1209, 128], [1209, 200], [1004, 200]],
  'EC~L',
  0.18826377391815186),
 ([[177, 179], [349, 179], [349, 241], [177, 241]], 'OKI', 0.9966741294455473),
 ([[180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]],
  'Oki Eleclric Industry Co',
  0.8091106257361781),
 ([[435, 243], [469, 243], [469, 263], [435, 263]], 'Ltd', 0.9978489622393302),
 ([[180, 265], [668, 265], [668, 293], [180, 293]],
  '4-11-22 , Shibaura, Minalo-ku, Tokyo 108-855| Japan',
  0.6109240973537998),
 ([[180, 291], [380, 291], [380, 318], [180, 318]],
  'Tel +81-3-5440-4884',
  0.9406430290171053)]
```

How to write a python code which prints the above format similar to below one:

```
[1004, 128, 1209, 128, 1209, 200, 1004, 200], 
'EC~L'
##################
[177, 179, 349, 179, 349, 241, 177, 241],
'OKI'
##################
[180, 236, 422, 236, 422, 268, 180, 268],
'Oki Eleclric Industry Co'
##################
[435, 243, 469, 243, 469, 263, 435, 263], 
'Ltd'
##################
[180, 265, 668, 265, 668, 293, 180, 293],
'4-11-22 , Shibaura, Minalo-ku, Tokyo 108-855| Japan'
##################
[180, 291, 380, 291, 380, 318, 180, 318],
'Tel +81-3-5440-4884'
```

**Can anyone help me with this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'll contribute with this one-liner solution.

```py
print("\n##################\n".join(("{},\n'{}'".format([x for item in items[0] for x in item], items[1])) for items in bounds))
```

Which produces the exact same format as the asker's desire:

```
[1004, 128, 1209, 128, 1209, 200, 1004, 200],
'EC~L'
##################
[177, 179, 349, 179, 349, 241, 177, 241],
'OKI'
##################
[180, 236, 422, 236, 422, 268, 180, 268],
'Oki Eleclric Industry Co'
##################
[435, 243, 469, 243, 469, 263, 435, 263],
'Ltd'
##################
[180, 265, 668, 265, 668, 293, 180, 293],
'4-11-22 , Shibaura, Minalo-ku, Tokyo 108-855| Japan'
##################
[180, 291, 380, 291, 380, 318, 180, 318],
'Tel +81-3-5440-4884'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly:

```
for l, s, _ in bounds:
    print([lll for ll in l for lll in ll])
    print(s)
    print('##################')
```

Output:

```
[1004, 128, 1209, 128, 1209, 200, 1004, 200]
EC~L
##################
[177, 179, 349, 179, 349, 241, 177, 241]
OKI
##################
[180, 236, 422, 236, 422, 268, 180, 268]
Oki Eleclric Industry Co
##################
[435, 243, 469, 243, 469, 263, 435, 263]
Ltd
##################
[180, 265, 668, 265, 668, 293, 180, 293]
4-11-22 , Shibaura, Minalo-ku, Tokyo 108-855| Japan
##################
[180, 291, 380, 291, 380, 318, 180, 318]
Tel +81-3-5440-4884
##################
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
from itertools import chain

for numbers, description, _ in bounds:
    numbers = list(chain(*numbers))
    print(f"{numbers},\n"
          f"'{description}'\n"
          "##################")
```

Output:

```
[1004, 128, 1209, 128, 1209, 200, 1004, 200],
'EC~L'
##################
[177, 179, 349, 179, 349, 241, 177, 241],
'OKI'
##################
[180, 236, 422, 236, 422, 268, 180, 268],
'Oki Eleclric Industry Co'
##################
[435, 243, 469, 243, 469, 263, 435, 263],
'Ltd'
##################
[180, 265, 668, 265, 668, 293, 180, 293],
'4-11-22 , Shibaura, Minalo-ku, Tokyo 108-855| Japan'
##################
[180, 291, 380, 291, 380, 318, 180, 318],
'Tel +81-3-5440-4884'
##################
```